# How to Pass List from Nested JSON with GSON Data to Recycler View

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, gson

POJO ParentClass-Model

```
public class EditorialsModel {

    @SerializedName("Editorial_Id")
    @Expose
    private String editorialId;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("content")
    @Expose
    private String content;
    @SerializedName("content_sample")
    @Expose
    private String contentSample;
    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private String image;
    @SerializedName("Words")
    @Expose
    private List<Word> words = null;

    public String getEditorialId() {
        return editorialId;
    }

    public void setEditorialId(String editorialId) {
        this.editorialId = editorialId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContentSample() {
        return contentSample;
    }

    public void setContentSample(String contentSample) {
        this.contentSample = contentSample;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public List<Word> getWords() {
        return words;
    }

    public void setWords(List<Word> words) {
        this.words = words;
    }

}
```

POJO ChildClass-Model

```
public class Word {

    @SerializedName("Word")
    @Expose
    private String word;
    @SerializedName("Meaning")
    @Expose
    private String meaning;
    @SerializedName("Synonym")
    @Expose
    private List<String> synonym = null;
    @SerializedName("Antonyms")
    @Expose
    private List<String> antonyms = null;

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getMeaning() {
        return meaning;
    }

    public void setMeaning(String meaning) {
        this.meaning = meaning;
    }

    public List<String> getSynonym() {
        return synonym;
    }

    public void setSynonym(List<String> synonym) {
        this.synonym = synonym;
    }

    public List<String> getAntonyms(int position) {
        return antonyms;
    }

    public void setAntonyms(List<String> antonyms) {
        this.antonyms = antonyms;
    }

}
```

I have Parsed data from JSON using GSON like this

```
                        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder=new GsonBuilder();
                        Gson gson=gsonBuilder.create();
                        List<EditorialsModel> posts = new ArrayList<>();
                        //EditorialsModel[] users=gson.fromJson(response,EditorialsModel[].class);
                        posts = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response, EditorialsModel[].class));
                        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, posts);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have passed the posts list to recycler view but unable to access getters methods from Word Class

The following Code to Get Parent Methods works Fine

```
    holder.songTitle.setText("Id: " + itemList.get(position).getEditorialId());
    holder.songYear.setText("Title: " + itemList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.songAuthor.setText("Content : " + itemList.get(position).getContentSample());
```

But unable to get child Methods like this

```
holder.synonyms.setText(itemList.get(position).getWords().size());
```

Comment: what about `holder.synonyms.setText(itemList.get(position).getWords().length()` ???

Comment: That is not working getting syntax errors

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that `itemList.get(position).getWords().size()` is an `int`, which means you're invoking `TextView.setText(int)` instead of `TextView.setText(String)`, and it is very unlikely that there's a string resource with that particular id (and if there is, it's exceedingly unlikely that it's the one you want).